# Prove that the implicit function is defined everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove this problem:

> Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ from $C^k$ class $(k \geq 1)$. Suppose there is a point $(x_0, y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and a constant M such as $f(x_0,y_0) = 0, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) \neq 0$ and $\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) \bigg/ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) \right| \leq M$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there is an unique $y = \xi(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ such as $f(x,\xi(x)) = 0$ and the function $\xi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^k$.

For the most part this problem can be proved using the implicit function theorem. However, the implicit function theorem can only guarantee an open interval around $x_0$, say I, within which the function $\xi(x)$ is defined and its unique. The problem asks to prove that this function is defined everywhere, from the fact that there is a single point $(x_0,y_0)$ there the function $f$ is constant equals to $0$.

From what I understand (and please correct me if I'm wrong), because we have added the condition
$\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) \bigg/ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) \right| \leq M$, the function $\xi(x)$ is uniformly continuous (actually it's Lipchitz, but we don't need that). Being uniformly continuous we know that this function is not "exploding" anywhere for each limited subinterval within $I$ (so it doesn't have asymptotes in at $x$ so to speak). However I was not able to formally prove this last part. Maybe I can use connectivity of $\mathbb{R}$, but still not clear.

Can anyone help me understanding how to prove this last fact assuming that we known $\xi(x)$ is unique and defined within an open interval $I$ around $x_0$ (as implicit function theorem states).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $\xi\colon\operatorname{dom}\xi\subseteq\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is maximally defined.

- By IFT, if $\xi$ is defined at $x$, it is defined on an open neighbourhood of $x$.  In other words $\operatorname{dom}\xi$ is open.
- On the other hand, since we have $\xi$ uniformly continuous and $\mathbb{R}$ complete, we can extend $\xi$ to a continuous $\overline{\xi}\colon\overline{\operatorname{dom}\xi}\to\mathbb{R}$.  Since $f$ is continuous, we would still have $f(x,\overline{\xi}(x))=0$ for all $x$.  So maximality of $\xi$ gives $\xi=\overline{\xi}$.

So $\operatorname{dom}\xi$ is both open and closed, hence connectedness of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\operatorname{dom}\xi\neq\varnothing$ (since $\xi(x_0)=y_0$) gives $\operatorname{dom}\xi=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hm, let me see if I understood: because of uniform continuity we know any sequence $X_n$ in x that converges, will certainly have the existing limit $\xi(X_n) = b$. And b is for sure in the closure of $dom\xi$. So the domain of $\xi$ is also closed.. is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that is the argument.

Comment: Does this argument rely on $f $ going from $\mathbb R^2$  to $\mathbb R$? Would it work if it went from $\mathbb R^{n+m}$ to $\mathbb R^{m}$?